# Reload values for draw circle

Tags: swift

Hi I'm creating a semicircle that updates your line widh depending on the values I give you that are always varying. I want to know how to update the values to determine the end angle and that these are always updated. Thanks

```
class Circle: UIView {  
//These 2 var (total dictionary and Secondary dictionary) have the number of the keys and the values ​​are always varying because they are obtained from json data
    var dictionaryTotal: [String:String] = ["a":"153.23", "b":"162.45", "c":"143.65", "d":"140.78", "e":"150.23"]

    var dictionarySecundario: [String:String] = ["w":"153.23", "l":"162.45", "v":"143.65"]

    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 25

    // circles radius
    var half = CGFloat.pi
    var quarter = CGFloat(3 * CGFloat.pi / 2)

    func drawCircleCenteredAtVariavel(center:CGPoint, withRadius radius:CGFloat) -> UIBezierPath{
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: centerOfCircleView, radius: halfOfViewsSize, startAngle: half, endAngle: CGFloat(((CGFloat(self.dictionarySecundario.count) * CGFloat.pi) / CGFloat(self. dictionaryTotal.count)) + CGFloat.pi), clockwise: true)

        circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth

        UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.88, blue: 0.70, alpha: 1).set()

        return circlePath
    }
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        drawCircleCenteredAtVariavel(center: centerOfCircleView, withRadius: halfOfViewsSize).stroke()

    }

}
```

[This is the picture of semicircle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74efI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish, so this isn't really answer, but it's more than I wanted to type in a comment.

The first thing you should do is separate responsibilities in so the `Circle` class above should only be responsible for drawing the semicircle for a particular configuration.

For example, a semicircular progress view based on your code above:

```
class CircleProgressView: UIView {
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 25
    var barColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.88, blue: 0.70, alpha: 1)
    var progress: Float = 0
    {
        didSet {
            progress = max(min(progress, 1.0), 0.0)
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    func semicirclePath(at center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat, percentage: Float) -> UIBezierPath {
        let endAngle = CGFloat.pi + (CGFloat(percentage) * CGFloat.pi)
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius, startAngle: CGFloat.pi, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

        circlePath.lineWidth = lineWidth

        return circlePath
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        barColor.set()

        let center = CGPoint.init(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
        let radius = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)/2 - lineWidth/2
        semicirclePath(at: center, radius: radius, percentage: progress).stroke()
    }
}
```

Then, outside of this class, you would have other code that would determine what `progress` is based on the JSON values you're receiving.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your drawCircleCenteredAtVariavel works, you should redraw whenever the lineWidth value is changed. Try this

```
var lineWidth: CGFloat = 25 {
    didSet {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    drawCircleCenteredAtVariavel(center: centerOfCircleView, withRadius: halfOfViewsSize).stroke()
}
```